# GetAddress.io and 'No Access Control Allow Origin' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use [getAddress.io](https://getaddress.io/Documentation#usage), and while the syntax is very simple, I'm trying to write my backend management that can get whitelisted domains and usage etc.

So here is my call in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: " https://api.getAddress.io/v2/usage",
    context: document.body,
    method: "GET",
    data: {"api-key": getAddressAPIKey}
}).done(function(results) {
    $("div.usage").append(results);
});
```

All seems to be up to scatch.  However it returns the following error:

```
Failed to load https://api.getaddress.io/security/ip-address-whitelist?api-key=[apikey]: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://admin.awme.local' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What am I doing wrong? I understand what the error is about as I've written my own APIs but this is a public API that I obviously dont have control over - and so therefore I cannot modify their code to allow me access.  This is a paid for service so I should just be able to query it and get my data back.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Maybe the service is not intended to be used directly from web clients, but instead from your own server.

Comment: Is getAddressAPIKey a function? should it be `getAddressAPIKey()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to whitelist either your domain(if you are accessing the API from client), or your server IP if using backend.

https://getaddress.io/Documentation#domain-whitelist

Just make a simple post request with you admin-key(NOT API KEY) the params(NOT IN BODY) and your domain name in the body and set Content-Type to application/json.

Here is an example request with the response using postman.

[image: postman example request]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the API has [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) set up. Try adding `dataType: "jsonp"` as a parameter in your AJAX request. If that doesn't work, try using something like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The problem is that the API *doesn't* have CORS set up.

Comment: It doesnt make sense for a paid for service to not allow Cross Domain, surley, the whole point is that with a valid API-KEY I can access it from my own domain?

Comment: @Chud37 Yeah, it doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you are sending the API key correctly? Since as @Musa saw, `getAddressAPIKey()` is never invoked since you wrote it without the parantheses.

Comment: @BojanIvanac getAddressAPIKey is just a variable that I didnt include but yeah I sending it correctly.  I am writing the code now in PHP because that works.  I guess they just dont want people writing their management in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query directly from the browser, you have to query through a proxy like nginx or apache. You throw your request to the proxy and the proxy passes them to the other public API

Answer (score 0):

May be the return type from the controller was not provided , This error mostly occurs when 
return type is not mentioned or kept as dynamic and if the return type object contains any child elements .Just mention a proper return type.

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your error message:

'https://api.getaddress.io/security/ip-address-whitelist?api-key=[apikey]'

..is not related to the code you have provided.

I assume there is more code in in your page that uses the above URL?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read its [document](https://getaddress.io/Documentation#domain-whitelist)? I'm not familiar with this getAddress.io, but it seems you have to add your domain and IP to its whitelist.

Checkout [Domain Whitelist](https://getaddress.io/Documentation#domain-whitelist) and [IP Address Whitelist](https://getaddress.io/Documentation#ip-address-whitelist)